# Convert a number to Human readable format (e.g. 1.5k, 5m, 1b) in Dart?

Tags: dart, flutter

i'm developing an app related to social messanging and i want to convert big numbers to Human readable format (e.g. 1500 to 1.5k) and also i'm new to Dart.
Your help will be appreciated.

Comment: `print(NumberFormat.compactCurrency(decimalDigits: 1, symbol: '').format(1500));`

Comment: this package may help you https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_money_formatter

Answer (score 78, accepted):

You can use the NumberFormat class of flutter which has some in built functions for results you want..

[Check out this link for NumberFormat class of flutter](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/intl/NumberFormat/NumberFormat.compactCurrency.html)

**Example:**
This is one way if you want to use currency..

```
var _formattedNumber = NumberFormat.compactCurrency(
  decimalDigits: 2,
  symbol: '', // if you want to add currency symbol then pass that in this else leave it empty.
).format(numberToFormat);

print('Formatted Number is: $_formattedNumber');
```

**Example:**
This example is with locale.

```
var _formattedNumber = NumberFormat.compactCurrency(
  decimalDigits: 2,
  locale: 'en_IN'
  symbol: '',
).format(numberToFormat);

print('Formatted Number is: $_formattedNumber');
```

The output of this is code would be:

**If 1000 is entered then 1K is the output**

Another way is by just using `NumberFormat.compact()` which gives the desired output...

```
// In this you won't have to worry about the symbol of the currency.
var _formattedNumber = NumberFormat.compact().format(numberToFormat);
print('Formatted Number is: $_formattedNumber');
```

The output of above example will also be:

**If 1000 is entered then 1K is the output**

I tried this and is working...

Comment: actually NumberFormat.compactLong will answer the question better because he is not using currency.

Comment: yes that can also be done...but this gives complete string instead of just M for million and K for thousand...

Comment: add '.toLowerCase()' if you want the K to be small 

Comment: for 100000 it shows like 100K but I want it as 1L is it is possible?

Comment: You can use locale paramter and pass like this "en_IN". Example: locale: 'en_IN'. Use it in "compactCurrency".

Comment: Not work at all

Answer (score -7):

**Make a class and used its static method every where.**

```
class NumberFormatter{
  static String formatter(String currentBalance) {
    try{
      // suffix = {' ', 'k', 'M', 'B', 'T', 'P', 'E'};
      double value = double.parse(currentBalance);

      if(value < 1000000){ // less than a million
        return value.toStringAsFixed(2);
      }else if(value >= 1000000 && value < (1000000*10*100)){ // less than 100 million
        double result = value/1000000;
        return result.toStringAsFixed(2)+"M";
      }else if(value >= (1000000*10*100) && value < (1000000*10*100*100)){ // less than 100 billion
        double result = value/(1000000*10*100);
        return result.toStringAsFixed(2)+"B";
      }else if(value >= (1000000*10*100*100) && value < (1000000*10*100*100*100)){ // less than 100 trillion
        double result = value/(1000000*10*100*100);
        return result.toStringAsFixed(2)+"T";
      }
    }catch(e){
      print(e);
    }
  }
}
```